# scroll position on Ajax's Timer OnTick event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Inside the one of contentPlaceHolder of the masterpage I'm using Iframe. And In Iframe suppose, IfrmPage.aspx I'm using update panel where timer control is updating the page for each certain duration.

So, what I'm trying to do is settng the focus on textbox after OnTick event.  I'm using following line:

ScriptManager1.SetFocus(this.txtMessage.ClientID);

This works correctly. However, Main page or I should say masterpage's scrollbar changes their position which is annoying.

Please share your valuable experience.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seaching on the google I found the answer.

Now I'm setting the focus to txtMessage(textbox) using javascript and remove this code:
`ScriptManager1.SetFocus(this.txtMessage.ClientID);`

final answer is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
     function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
         if (args.get_panelsUpdated().length > 0) {
             $get('txtMessage').focus();
         }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback on the page declaration of IfrmPage.aspx?

Comment: After seaching on the google I found the answer.

Now I'm setting the focus to txtMessage(textbox) using javascript and removie this code: ScriptManager1.SetFocus(this.txtMessage.ClientID);

final answer is here:

<script type="text/javascript">
         var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
         function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
             if (args.get_panelsUpdated().length > 0) {
                 $get('txtMessage').focus();
             }
         }
    </script>

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but this is a useful property nonetheless. It goes on the page directive at the top of the page e.g:

<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ... %>

...however, I do not know if this will work with ajax involved.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx